# two conversionService bean created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, converters

I am getting an error while trying to up my application

```
Description:

Field conversionService in com.profectus.dashboard.service.impl.DashBoardSettingsServiceimpl required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - mvcConversionService: defined by method 'mvcConversionService' in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]
    - defaultConversionService: defined by method 'defaultConversionService' in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Why 2 beans are created and how to keep only one converter, I just want only spring core converter who can convert entity to pojo or pojo to entity.

I am stuck because of this issue, any lead would be helpful.

Service class code:-

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService;
//other imports

@Service
public class DashBoardSettingsServiceimpl implements DashBoardSettingsService {

    @Autowired
    private DashBoardSettingJpaRepository dashBoardSettingRepo;

    @Autowired
    private ConversionService conversionService;

    @Override
    public DashBoardSettingResponse save(UserInfo userInfo, DashBoardSettingRequest request) {

        //other coded
        DashBoardSettigEntity entity = conversionService.convert(request.getDashBoardSetting(),
                DashBoardSettigEntity.class);


        DashBoardSettigEntity entityRetrieve = dashBoardSettingRepo.save(entity);

        DashBoardSetting setting = conversionService.convert(entityRetrieve, DashBoardSetting.class);

        DashBoardSettingResponse response = new DashBoardSettingResponse();

        response.addDashBoardSetting(setting);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you Injecting conversionService ?
Maybe you need add @Qualifier("mvcConversionService")

Comment: I am not adding any qualifier

Comment: if I add qualifier it will work but my question is how it is creating two beans

Comment: If you want use 2 of them you can add 2 Qualifiers

Comment: My question is I am not getting why 2 beans are created.

Comment: Can you show the code of DashBoardSettingsServiceimpl.

Comment: @luboskrnac, I have added the service class code

Answer (score 0):

Autowire type `DefaultConversionService` instead of `ConversionService`

Comment: Does not help, as `DefaultConversionService` is still of type `ConversionService`. Still results in `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: mvcConversionService,defaultConversionService`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it has something to do with spring data rest having its own ConversionService instance.

Can you try this:

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("mvcConversionService") ConversionService conversionService;
```

It worked for me.
Don't forget to add your converters to a WebMvcConfigurer implementation.